# sqlite : time difference between two dates in decimals

Tags: sqlite

I have two two timestamp fields (START,END) and a TIME_DIFF field which is of Integer type. I am trying to calculate the time between START and END field.. I created a trigger to do that :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TIME_DIFF]
AFTER UPDATE OF [END]
ON [KLOG]
BEGIN
update klog set TIME_DIFF =
cast(
      (      
        strftime('%s',KLOG.END) -        
 strftime('%s',KLOG.START) 
) as INT
) / 60/60;
END
```

This gives me result in whole hours.Anything between 0 and 59 minutes is neglected.

I am wondering how can I modify this trigger so it displays in decimals?

Meaning, if the time difference is 1 hour 59 minutes the result would display 1.59.If the time difference is 35 minutes it would display 0.35.

Comment: Did you thought it through? Remember that 1 hour is 60 min not 100. saying 1h 59 min is 1.59 is bit misleading. if i ware you i would simply remember time in minutes, and process them as needed (extract number of hours etc.) PS. why triger after update if you could do before update and set value via `new.TIME_DIFF = x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To interpret a number of seconds as a timestamp, use the [`unixepoch` modifier](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). Then you can simply use `strftime()` to format the value:

```
strftime('%H:%S',
         strftime('%s',KLOG.END) - strftime('%s',KLOG.START),
         'unixepoch')
```

If you use Julian days instead of seconds, you do not need a separate modifier:

```
strftime('%H:%S',
         julianday(KLOG.END) - julianday(KLOG.START))
```